# Python Rar All File In Directory, Each File Different Directory

Tags: python, rar

It feels like this is a colossally stupid question, but the documentation for rar as a whole is pretty sketchy, and using python to rar pulls an insane number of hits, none of them even seem to be attempting what I'm trying to do (which I find somewhat odd).

I have a directory with a bunch of files:
FILE_1.ext
FILE_2.ext
FILE_3.ext
...
FILE_N.ext

The names aren't necessarily uniform, neither are the extensions.
I'm looking for a python script to:
for all files in directory that don't start with .
rar a -m0 -R -v1g FILE_NAME.rar "FILE_NAME" #Note: FILE_NAME.rar doesn't have the ".ext"

The "rar a -m0 -R -v1g FILE_NAME.rar "FILE_NAME"" part is what I use when I'm sending a shell command, for one file, and I have to enter the FILE_NAME myself, etc.  Hasn't been a problem, but now I'm dealing with a lot of large files, and it's too much to enter them all in one-by-one, but I need to have each file be it's own volume.

Comment: Any reason you can't use tar/zip?

Comment: Why Python?  I love Python dearly, but this particular problem would be easily solved with a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
    import os
    for file_n in os.listdir(DIRECTORY_NAME):
         if not file_n.startswith('.') and not file_n.endswith('.rar'):
              os.system('rar a -m0 -R -v1g %s.rar "%s"' %(os.path.splitext(file_n)[0], file_n))
```